# Select statement Invalid number ORA-01722 Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

Below example works fine, but after try to select statement in `IN`

clause I get the an error.

```
select * from emp where empno in ('7839','7698','7782');  --works
```

In my table test column column1 I have --> '7839','7698','7782'

```
select * from emp where empno in (select column1 from test);
```

The error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Any solution how fix this, how convert string to number?

Comment: Could you also provide the schema for table "emp"?

Comment: Checkt the emp.empno type. When you use  "empno in ('7839','7698','7782')" probably the implicit conversion is being applied, and when you try to use subquery an error occures, becouse you try to compare character with the number, probably.

Comment: Provide the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements and sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements.

Comment: It's almost as though not having a data model which complies with [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) is a bad idea which leads to horrible queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'7839','7698','7782'` is a string, it is not a list of strings so you cannot use it as a list in an `IN` operator. Instead, check whether the `emp` string (with surrounding quotes) is a substring of your `column1` string.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp ( empno ) As
SELECT 7698 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE test ( column1 ) AS
SELECT '''7839'',''7698'',''7782''' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   emp e
WHERE  EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM   test t
  WHERE  t.column1 LIKE '%''' || e.empno || '''%'
)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | EMPNO |
> | ----: |
> |  7698 |
> ```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e37499081861d76e5797f552e9a270be)

---

If you have `7839,7698,7782` rather than a quoted delimited string then use:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp ( empno ) As
SELECT 7698 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE test ( column1 ) AS
SELECT '7839,7698,7782' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   emp e
WHERE  EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM   test t
  WHERE  ',' || t.column1 || ',' LIKE '%,' || e.empno || ',%'
)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | EMPNO |
> | ----: |
> |  7698 |
> ```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b9ff77611a721b7f1fe5a343b9682506)

Comment: Hi, Is it posssible use eg. 7839,7698,7782  instead '7839','7698','7782'

Answer (score -1):

An ORA-01722 error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a number.

Comment: SELECT * FROM emp 
WHERE empno IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER(column1) FROM test WHERE TO_NUMBER(TRIM(column1)) = 1);